# How do I know the offset of a time zone from GMT by using its id in joda?

Tags: java, mysql, jodatime

I have a MySQL database in which one column is of type `DATETIME` and stores the values in IST (as my server time zone is `IST`).

I am getting a two string in `EST` from the user for which I need to match the date part in my database with that column.

I am using this query :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where date(convert_tz(`myDate`,'+05:30','-05:00'))
between  '2012-12-01' and '2012-12-02';
```

Note: That in my database `mysql.time_zone` is empty meaning I cannot use `strings like`GMT`etc in my query, they instructed me to download a package, but I don't want to download it, its fine for me to use`00:05` as I will be framing my query in Java.

This query runs fine as I have hardcoded the the time zone offset (for `EST`.

But I am worried that this query will give wrong data for the dates that fall in Daylight timings i.e. for `EDT`.

So how do I get the time zone difference (meaning it should return '-05:00' for EST and '-04:00 for EDT ) so that I can directly use them when building my query string in java.

My query string may look like :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where date(convert_tz(`myDate`,'+05:30','???')) 
between '2012-12-01' and '2012-12-02';
```

where I want the value at ??? to be dynamically allocated using a prepared statement.

I am using Joda Time API, but don't have much knowledge of it, whether it has something that can return me the timezone offser for a given timezone string.

Comment: "and stores the values in IST (as my server time zone is IST)" - that's a non-sequitur. You should almost certainly be storing *all* data as UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know but it is there in the database already stored in IST

Comment: I would *strongly* encourage you to raise this with your colleagues as an issue, and fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that:

- You start storing your values as UTC, for the sake of sanity. (The data shouldn't depend on the server's location.)
- You compute the UTC value for the start/end points within Java (using a `DateTime` set in the right time zone, and then converting to UTC)
- You pass the UTC start/end directly into the query via SQL parameters (*don't* include the values in the SQL text) and avoid the database doing any conversion

If you really, really can't change the database to use UTC instead, you should convert your "target timezone" values into IST values instead, and pass *those* to the database. Again, the query doesn't need to do conversion: convert your inputs beforehand instead.

Comment: How do I store time in utc as I am getting a Calendar object with time zone as GMT and the I am inserting it as `psInsert.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(myobject.getCreated().getTimeInMillis()));`

Comment: @Abu: You'd have to show complete code, to be honest. Are you certain that it's not *already* using UTC? A `Timestamp` doesn't really have a time zone... It's possible that you should ignore any MySQL GUIs, as they may *interpret* values in a particular time zone...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - yes I am using MySQL query browser to view my database, how shall I check whether the values are stroed in UTC or not? Shall I use MySQL command prompt ?

Comment: @Abu: I would create a known value from Java - `new Timestamp(0)` would be a simple one, as 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z - and see how that looks when you fetch it back, and also what it looks like from MySQL query browsers. When you understand how a known, fixed point behaves, it'll be easier to reason about real data.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Thank you very much I will definitely do that to gain more insight.